# JavaScript in gridview HyperLinkField NavigateUrl

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a List of Items which is binded to GridView:

```
class Item
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    }

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">                 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" />
                <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="CategoryName" NavigateUrl="javascript:alert('Hello World');"/>               
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

All that I need to show the CategoryName in the alert window instead of 'Hello world'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a template field instead:

```
   <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a href="javascript:alert('<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>');"><%# Eval("CategoryName") %></a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Also, best practices suggest using onclick in Anchors instead of javascript: Pseudo-Protocol

Comment: It causes to Expected ')' error: Code:0, Line:1, Char:18. I had no cognizance of the situation. I posted the first line in the comments to the first answer

Comment: Don't forget to escape ' in the CategoryName!